# Java Beginner: cost of threading over serial

Tags: java, multithreading

I was wondering If I have  (N) Double vectors, each with large length say 10,000 and I wanted to thread the operation(multiply by 3 for each vector ) which by making (N) threads.

I was wondering If there was a cost of using parallel (N)  threads over  Serial one by one operations ? Cost( memory, speed, etc) ?

or using threading is actually better idea since I read it would use available cores ?

Comment: Related: [What is the rough "cost" of a thread?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492711/java-what-is-the-rough-cost-of-a-thread-cpu-cycles-memory)

Comment: Stating the obvious, I guess, but since I can't see it mentioned elsewere: it doesn't make sense to create more threads than you have cores, but other than that, it depends on the overhead of creating a thread compared to the overall runtime of the operation.  You would need to test it to find out where these factors intersect.

Comment: If you want massively parallell vector-operations, you could look into CUDA, but that would be tricky to do from Java, and embarrasingly non-portable.

Comment: hopefully you are not storing the data into java.lang.Double.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes: Each thread will use up resources: at least memory, but possibly also OS processes or other OS resouces. The details will depend on the JVM implementation.

If the memory usage becomes to high you  might also take a performance hit due to more frequent GC, paging and what ever computers do to manage their memory

Answer (score 0):

When performing memory intensive operations, the size of your cache is more likely to be important than the size of your main memory. As the lower caches are shared, intensive use of this one cache may not give you much scalability when using multiple cores.  However if you minimise the amount of data each core is using or your operations are non-trivial you can get near linear scalability

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't want to create new threads for each vector (the overhead of creating a new thread is significant). However it may make sense to do this work in a [thread pool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool_pattern) to exploit multiple cores.

It sounds as if:

- The calculations are large enough that you would benefit from harnessing multiple threads
- The individual vectors are large enough that they could be used as chunks of work

If the above is true, then it may make sense to use a [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) which will enable you to send each vector to the pool of threads for processing.