# java tcp server to many connections

Tags: java, multithreading, tcp, handler

I wrote a simple TCP server to transfare some user Data to it and save it in an simple MySQL table. If i now run more than 2000 clients after each other it stops working. While running i get some `IO error java.io.EOFException` you may also see the misstake i made for that. But the most importand is that i get this

```
 IO error java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
    at java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Thread.start(Unknown Source)
    at Server.main(Server.java:49)
```

Enough Memory schould be there but the threads are still running and i dont see where i made the misstake that they dont get terminated. So i got up to 3900 threads running than.
So here is the part of the Server:

```
try {
    // create new socket
    ServerSocket sock = new ServerSocket(port);
    textArea.setText(textArea.getText() + "Server started\n");
    while (true) {
        // accept the connection
            Socket newsock = sock.accept();
        // handle the action
        Thread t = new ThreadHandler(newsock);
            newsock.setSoTimeout(2000); // adding client timeout
        t.start();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
```

guess really simple. Here is how i handle the socket:

```
class ThreadHandler extends Thread {
    private Socket socket;
    private MySQLConnection sqlConnection;

    ThreadHandler(Socket s) {
        socket = s;
        sqlConnection = new MySQLConnection();
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(
                    socket.getOutputStream());
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(
                    socket.getInputStream()));
            Server.textArea.append((new Date()) + "\nClient connected IP: " + socket.getInetAddress().toString()+"\n");

            int firstLine = in.readInt(); // get first line for switch

            switch (firstLine) {
            case 0:
                // getting the whole objekt for the database in own lines!
                String name2 = in.readUTF();
                int level2 = in.readInt();
                int kp2 = in.readInt();
                String skill = in.readUTF();

                LeadboardElement element2 = new LeadboardElement();
                element2.setName(name2);
                element2.setLevel(level2);
                element2.setKillPoints(kp2);
                element2.setSkill(skill);
                sqlConnection.saveChaToLeadboard(element2);
                break;
                //case 1 return the top10
###.... shorten here the rest of the cases
                out.close();
            in.close();
            //close this socket
            socket.close();
                    Server.textArea.append("Client disconnected IP: " + socket.getInetAddress().toString()+ "\n" + (new Date())
                            + "\n----------------------------------------------------\n");
            // autoscrolldown
            Server.textArea.setCaretPosition(Server.textArea.getDocument()
                    .getLength());
         } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("IO error " + e);
            try {
                socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }finally{
        try {
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

the `saveChaToLeadboard` simply gets the name level kp and skill and uses a `preparedStatement` so save it to my MySQL Table.
I hope you can help me i just dont see the misstake of it. I think i need to Join it somewhere but if i put a join at the end of it (after socket.close()) it still does the same.

Here the save to database methode:

```
public void saveChaToLeadboard(LeadboardElement element) {
        try {
            // load driver
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(this.databaseURL
                    + DATABASE_NAME, this.user, this.password);
            // insert values into the prep statement
            preparedStatement = connection
                    .prepareStatement(PREP_INSERT_STATEMENT);
            preparedStatement.setString(1, element.getName());
            preparedStatement.setInt(2, element.getLevel());
            preparedStatement.setInt(3, element.getKillPoints());
            if(!element.getSkill().equalsIgnoreCase("")){
                preparedStatement.setString(4, element.getSkill());
            }else{
                preparedStatement.setString(4, null);
            }
            // execute
            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
            connection.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Server.textArea.append(e.getMessage() + "\n");
            Server.textArea.setCaretPosition(Server.textArea.getDocument()
                    .getLength());
            try {
                connection.close();
            } catch (SQLException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Thanks alot! 
Regards

Comment: Are you closing the accepted sockets at EOS? at IOExceptions?

Comment: 3900 is a lot of threads - anything above 1000 is probably a high limit on a standard desktop machine.

Comment: It's a good machine dont worry about it but i guess 3900 is still to much because they dont get closed. Yea i close the Socket at the acception. Ill add this to code

Comment: @Benjamin My point was: you can't create an infinite number of threads, even on a good machine. You should use a threadpool and a connection pool.

Comment: yes i know but shouldnt they get collected by the GC if they are done? there is no while true in it its just a simple add to database. The server will never get an load ov 2000 at the same time but if i get 2000 in a sequence it will also not work because the threads are still active even from the first connection.

Comment: How do you know the threads are still running (are you doing a thread dump?) and how are you sure those threads are actually finished doing their work?

Comment: because my taskmanager tells me that i got 3900 threads and if i close the server they drop to 700....

Comment: And how do you know the threads have finished and aren't, for example, still inserting data into the database?

Comment: after `socket.close()` i print a client done which comes up at every connection. I got a connect IP and a disconect IP in front of the work and after the work so i always see if the process worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `run()` method is mangled, but I suspect that part of the problem is that you are not always closing network sockets and streams.  In particular, I suspect that you are not closing them if there is an exception while reading, or processing the data you read.  You should always close sockets and streams in a `finally` block (or the Java 7 equivalent).

Another potential problem is that some of the connections may be stalling due to the other end not sending data.  To deal with that, you would need to set a read timeout on the socket ... so that connections to slow / stuck clients can be closed.

Finally, it is probably unrealistic to even try to process 2000+ connections in parallel with a thread per connection.  That's a LOT of resources<sup>1</sup>.  I recommend you use a thread pool with a fixed upper limit in the low hundreds, and stop accepting new connections if all threads are in use.

---

<sup>1 - Each thread stack occupies at least 64K of memory on a HotSpot JVM, and possibly as much of 1Mb.  Then there are the Heap resources that the thread directly or indirectly refers to, and OS resources needed to maintain the state of the threads and the sockets.  For 2000 threads, that's probably multiple Gb of memory.</sup>

Comment: i added a timeout and also the finally block the threads are still running. ill add the changed code

Comment: Thanks alot for the Bonus informations! I just changed it to a ThreadPool with the help of an `ExecutorService` for my handling threads. Max threads are 100 atm which works good. I used this http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-multithreaded-servers/thread-pooled-server.html with some small modification. Hope thats a good/better solution.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO 2000 threads is on the high side for a single process and 2000 database connections definately is.

Regardless of whether or not you're hitting limits with 2000 incoming connections, your approach simply will not scale.

To acheive scalability you need to look at using resource pools - this means:

- a pool of reader threads reading from the sockets queuing the data for processing.
- a pool of worker threads processing the data queued by the reader threads.
- a pool of database connections used by the worker threads - this connection pool could be adjusted so that each worker thread has it's own connection but the important thing is that you don't continually open and close database connections.

Look at the [concurreny API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) for the thread pools and the [NIO API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/package-summary.html) for the IO.

This arrangement will allow you to tune your server to acheive the desired throughput.

Comment: this is actually not the Problem. The problem is, that the threads are still aktiv even after 5 minutes thats why i cant create new. The requests i make are done in like 0ms but the thread is still aktive after a minute. Else i guess the small requests wouldnt make a problem even if i make around 2000 requests. I try this with a for(2000) and simply send the characterdata.

Comment: It the `ThreadHandler.run` method is exiting then the thread will die - it's as simple as that.  But trust me on your approach - creating a thread has a cost (see this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492711/java-what-is-the-rough-cost-of-a-thread-cpu-cycles-memory), as does each database connection.  You can pay that cost upfront when server starts by creating a pool or with every request that comes in as you are currently doing.

Comment: Thanks on that! I used a `ExecutorService` now with a limit to 100threads. Works way faster now thanks!